# Convert decimal integers into 4-bit binary

Tags: c#

I want to convert decimal integers taken from an array and convert into 4-bit binary and store each of the bit into array in c#

```
static void Main()
{
    BinaryInput a = new BinaryInput();
    int[] input = { 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 0 };
    int x;
    int[] bits = new int[36];
    ArrayList Actor = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        x = (int)input[i];
        string result = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
        bits = result.PadLeft(4, '0').Select(c =>int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
        Actor.Add(bits);
    }
}
```

The `ArrayList` `Actor` consists of 9 arrays and each array consist of binary number......but i want to add each of the binary bit in a single array as an individual element of the array or arraylist `{0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}`

Comment: That is what the `BitArray` class is for. `BitVector32` might be handy too if you want something more optimized, but will take some more work.

Comment: BTW a 4-bit integer is called a nibble.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a method to get the "bits" of a number like this

```
private static IEnumerable<int> ToBitSequence(this int num, int size)
{
    while (size > 0)
    {
        yield return num & 1;
        size--;
        num >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in the following way to get your desired results.

```
int[] input = { 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 4, 0 };
var bits = input.Reverse().SelectMany(i => i.ToBitSequence(4)).Reverse();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bits));
```

Results in

> 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

The reason for the two `Reverse` calls is because `ToBitSequence` will return the least significant bit first, so by feeding the number in reverse order and then reversing the results  you will get the bits from most significant to least starting with the first number in your list.

This is preferable to all the parsing and formatting between `char`, `string`, and `int` that you're currently doing.

However if you just change `Actor` to `List<int>` and do `Actor.AddRange(bits);` that would also work.

Comment: He also needs to realize the largest number he can put into any element of the input array is 15, otherwise he'll run over his 4-bit limit he set in the question. Very nice answer btw

Comment: @Kevin Actually my implementation let's you set the "limit", but you are correct that numbers over 15 will be truncated taking only the last 4 least significant bits.  Though the OP did seems to indicate that all the numbers will be single decimal digits (0-9).

Comment: Suggestion, change `int` to `BigInteger` and everyone will be happy :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitArray`

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(new byte[] { x });
int[] bits = b.Cast<bool>().Select(bit => bit ? 1 : 0).ToArray();
```

This will give you the bits, then use

```
bits.Take(4).Reverse()
```

to get the least significant 4 bits in most-significant order first for each number.

Comment: While this is a better way to convert a number to it's bits than what the OP has the real question is about getting a sequence of the "bits" instead of a sequence of "bit" arrays.