# Split array into subarrays of specific length

Tags: c#, linq

I know that similar questions were asked many times. However I didn't find solution which I need and also cannot find out it myself.

**My scenario**: I have array of `bytes`. Now I need to convert them into `bits` and then create array which will contains exact number of bits.

I am able to convert them into bits and create array of specific length, but only with 8 bits in every index.

**My code example**:

```
var blocks = byteArr.Select(byte => Convert.ToString(byte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))
    .Select((byte, i) => new { Value = byte, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 100)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

It returns [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8fE6.png). How you see on the screenshot, it creates array of '100 byte arrays' but what I need is array of '100 bits arrays' or better array of strings where every string has 100 bits.

Thanks for reply and help.

Comment: `byte` is not a valid variable name unless you precede it with a `@`, but really you should just pick another name, int this case `b` would be fine.

Comment: I just answered a similar question.  You might find the method in my answer handy here.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35780047/302918

Comment: @juharr, yes, it is, I had there letter but here into stack overflow question, I have edited it into byte and didn't realize that it is not valid. Thanks I will take a look

Comment: @juaharr, thanks for reply and link but it seems that it does not solve my problem. In your answer you are converting numbers into bits, but I have already array of bits (string of length 8), I just need join them and create array of strings length of 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
var blocks = byteArr.SelectMany(myByte => Convert.ToString(myByte , 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))
    .Select((bit, i) => new { Bit = bit, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 100)
    .Select(grp => new string(grp.Select(x => x.Bit).ToArray()))
    .ToArray();
```

The `SelectMany` will break your binary strings into the individual chars, then you'll group them into sets of 100 by the index.  Finally you just create the new string of those "char bits".

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly. Once I will gain 15 reputation, I will vote up :)) Thanks very much